# Angular dependency injection: providers vs imports

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-providers

the Angular documentation on dependency injection has confused me.
I understand that Angular DI works by specifying to the DI (the injector) something to "provide" via the providers array on the metadata object passed to NgModule (for the whole module) or Component (for just that component).

This question is **not** specific to reactive forms, but in the angular.io example for Reactive Forms it has the component defined as (simplified!):

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  template: '<p>Hello world</p>'
})
export class DepInjectionExample
{
     constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
     {
        //Use form builder here
     }
}
```

Now this works (I have a reactive form working), but how?  There is no "provider" for FormBuilder, either in the Component providers array or its containing NgModule providers array.  Yet the Angular DI documentation is insistent the providers array is the only way to register something for DI.  What's going on?  How can some injected things not need to be in the providers array?

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE with answer**

Ah!  I see from the providers page:
"when you import a module that has providers, those providers are also available to all the classes in the app as long they have the lookup token. For example, if you import the HttpClientModule into your AppModule, its providers are then available to the entire app and you can make HTTP requests from anywhere in your app."
https://angular.io/guide/providers

I did not realise that an imported module's providers automatically became providers for the importing module.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/form_providers.ts#L35 so if you import ReactiveFormsModule  you will be able to inject FormBuilder

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but why is it that something that is part of something that is imported becomes available to the DI/an injector?  My question is not "how to get Reactive Forms working", it's how can I be injecting without a provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReactiveFormsModule` provides the `FormBuilder Service`. So, when you `imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]` in your module you are providing `FormBuilder` too.

The `FormBuilder` is a feature of `ReactiveFormsModule`. It is like any other module that you add to your application. Another one that you can see this behaviour is `MatDialog` service that is provided by `MatDialogModule`.

This is the Module pattern used by Angular. We use `modules` to GROUP FEATURES as (`service, pipe, directive, routes and components`) and its dependencies.

In the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) they say:

> NgModules configure the injector and the compiler and help organize related things together.

As the user pointed out: "imported module's providers automatically became providers for the importing module."

Comment: That is helpful... can you point to where this is documented?  How are we to guess which modules don't require  their elements to be put in the providers array in order to be used by a component (e.g. ReactiveFormsModule's FormBuilder) and which do?

Comment: I'll accept this as it pointed me towards the answer I was looking for (which I put the my question edit).